# Why does .format(function()) not work, but % prints the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Code that I wrote:

```
def ball(f):  
    py_ball = f * 5
    u_ball = py_ball / 10  
    return py_ball, u_ball
print("py ball: {}, u ball: {}".format(ball(100)))
```

When I use `str.format`, it throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rear.py", line 5, in 
    print("py ball: {}, u ball: {}".format(ball(100)))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

But if I use `%` formatting:

```
print("py ball: %d, u ball: %d" % ball(100))
```

it works just fine and produces:

```
py ball: 500, u ball: 50
```

Comment: use `*ball(100)` to unpack the returned values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.format()` takes **separate arguments** for each slot, while `%` accepts a tuple or a single value. `ball()` returns a tuple, and that's a single argument as far as `str.format()` is concerned. Because your template has 2 slots, there is an argument missing for that second slot.

You have two options: Either accept a single argument for `.format()` and use formatting instructions to extract the nested elements, or pass in the tuple as separate arguments.

The latter can be done with the `*expr` call notation:

```
print("py ball: {}, u ball: {}".format(*ball(100)))
```

but the formatting specification lets you also address tuple elements:

```
print("py ball: {0[0]}, u ball: {0[1]}".format(ball(100)))
```

I used explicit numbering here to indicate that just one argument is expected, in position `0`; `0[0]` takes the first element of the tuple, `0[1]` takes the second.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string requires **two** arguments to `.format`, but you provide only one (which is a two-element tuple, but it is still **one** argument). 
On the other hand, `%` operator **requires** a single tuple as its right-hand argument, so it is OK. You could unpack your tuple using prefix asterisk operator:

```
b = ball(100)
print("py ball: {}, u ball: {}".format(*b))
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `ball()` is a single value - a tuple.

When you call `"...".format(ball(100))` you are passing that single value to a function that will eventually want two values.

When you call `"..." % ball(100)` you are supplying a tuple to the `%` operator, which expects a tuple!

Not surprisingly, it works in the second case and fails in the first case.

Try using the **splat** operator to flatten the tuple into the arguments of the call to `.format`, or try expanding the tuple yourself, or try using named parameter access in the `.format` call:

```
ball100 = ball(100)

"py ball: {}, u ball: {}".format(*ball100)   # splat! Flatten the tuple

"py ball: {}, u ball: {}".format(ball100[0], ball100[1]) # DIY

"py ball: {ball[0]}, u ball: {ball[1]}".format(ball=ball100) # named arg
```